# How can I import all class and method from python file?

Tags: python

I want to import all classes and methods from a python file. Currently I imported by writing their name, as like,
from utils import a,b,c,d

But I want to import without writing name.

python version 4.1
Thanks

Comment: Just `import utils`, then you need to use qualified name, ie. `utils.a`, `utils.b` etc

Comment: How can you be in python 4.1 ? python 3.9 is still in development ...

Comment: ``from __future__ import @Infant``

Answer (score 3):

You could use `from utils import *` but this isn't really recommended as it clutters up your namespace and can easily lead to conflicts. It also makes tracking down the location of code more difficult. It's better to just do `import utils`, then call `utils.whatever()` later on.

Answer (score 1):

It's not recommended as you may overwrite variables in your script but:

`from utils import *`

Answer (score 0):

You can just put:

`import package`

or

`from package import *`

Comment: Why the parentheses?

Comment: No, it just for reference